# Wait for exec.Cmd to return or receive message from channel go

Tags: go, asynchronous

I would like to gracefully shutdown my goroutines running os/exec cmd. How would I wait for either cmd.Wait() or a message from a channel.
Something like this:

```
for {
        select {
        case <-channel:
            fmt.Println("Exit Signal")
            cmd.Process.Kill()
            break
        case <- cmd.Wait():
            break
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Start a goroutine to wait on the process.  Use select to wait on completion of that goroutine or the message from the channel:

```
done := make(chan struct{})
go func() {
    cmd.Wait()
    close(done)
}()

select {
case <-done:
    // cmd.Wait() completed.
case <-channel:
    fmt.Println("Exit Signal")
    cmd.Process.Kill()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to rewrite using exec.CommandContext(ctx,path,args...) and let the channel cancel to ctx. Then you can just use cmd.Wait()